# How can I subset filtering a row per categories with a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, subset

How can i subset these lines of code with a for loop
I'm trying to subset these lines of code but I couldn't, I think that it could be done with a group by and a dictionary but I'm couldn't

```
df_belgium = df_sales[df_sales["Country"]=="Belgium"]
df_norway = df_sales[df_sales["Country"]=="Norway"]
df_portugal = df_sales[df_sales["Country"]=="portugal"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would be to loop through `["Belgium","Norway","portugal"]`, but trying to create objects with variable variable names like `df_{country_name}` is highly discouraged (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)), so I would recommend creating a dictionary to store your subset dataframes with the country names as keys.

You can use a [dict comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/):

```
df_sales_by_country = {country_name: df_sales[df_sales["Country"]==country_name] for country_name in ["Belgium","Norway","portugal"]}
```

Comment: This is not an efficient way to perform the task. The time complexity is O(n^2) for looping through the rows for each country. This will be very slow for a large number of countries.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal is to use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and to store the sub-DataFrames in a dictionary:

```
d = dict(df.groupby('Country'))
```

Then access `d['Belgium']` for example.

If you need to filter a subset of the countries:

```
# use a set for efficiency
keep = {'Belgium', 'Norway', 'Portugal'}

d = {key: g for key, g in df.groupby('Country') if country in keep}
```

or:

```
keep = ['Belgium', 'Norway', 'Portugal']

d = dict(df[df['Country'].isin(keep)].groupby('Country'))
```